# Every time I open my VS solution I get “Projects have recently been added to this solution. Do you want to get them from source control?”

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs

I don't know exactly how, but on a certain moment we ruined our complete visual studio solution. It wouldn't build anymore, nor clean, nor find any reference.

Afters hours of searching and trying to fix everything we got to the point that everything was building and running again.

However.. every time we open our solution we will get the message “Projects have recently been added to this solution. Do you want to get them from source control?”.

This is probably cause by trying to fix one thing and breaking something else.

How do we get rid of this message?

[image: Projects have recently been added to this solution. Do you want to get them from source control?]

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Thanks to some research and trying some various options this is what solved it in our case.

**1. Unbinding the solution file from TFS**

Unbind the solution file (.sln) from TFS. We did this (in visual studio of course) by going to the menu `File => Source Control => Change Source Control`.

[image: Unbinding the solution file]

**2. Cleaning the solution file by deleting globalsection**

We had to clean the solution file (.sln) by opening it in a text editor (we used notepad++). We removed all occurences of `GlobalSection(TeamFoundationVersionControl) = preSolution`. Including the mentioned starting tag and the ending tag `EndGlobalSection`.

**3. Bind the solution file to TFS again**

Finally we binded the solution file (.sln) to TFS again. We did this (in visual studio of course) by going to the menu `File => Source Control => Change Source Control`

[image: Binding the solution file to TFS again]

Thanks to http://www.nivisec.com/2008/09/vsts-projects-have-recently-been-added.html who pointed us in the right direction after some hours of research.

Comment: Hi, Tom B. Do you know whether historic is lost when you unbinding the solution from TFS?. Thanks in advance.

Comment: History is saved in TFS not in the binding of your local workspace so no history will not be lost.

Comment: Unbinding, restarting VS, and binding again worked for me in VS2017. Perhaps just closing and reopening the solution in place of restarting VS will work. It remains to be testet if I encounter this "bug" again. Anyway, fortunately I did not have to go through step 2.

Comment: For Visual Studio 2017 it looks like the "Change Source Control" menu item change to: File => Source Control => Advanced => Change Source Control

Comment: Make sure you are viewing *Source Control Explorer* and also make sure you have your *Solution* node highlighted in *Solution Explorer* before selecting `File>SourceControl>Advanced` (for VS2017)

Comment: Also, if this does not work for you, close your solution, edit your sln file per the instructions, then open your solution and unbind EVERYTHING and rebind it right after. This suggestion worked for me initially but the 2nd time I had to use this strategy instead.

Comment: This happens to me after creating a fresh branch from another branch. I don't understand why.

Comment: for me I had to delete the .vssscc file that is associated with the .sln, after doing a "unbind".  Then rebinding worked and the message stopped.

Answer (score 11):

I had this same error. Turned out to be a project that was deleted from source control but still referenced in the `.sln` file. Was difficult to spot as we had >100 projects in the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Had a same problem, project was removed from solution but for some reason `SccNumberOfProjects` under `GlobalSection(TeamFoundationVersionControl) = preSolution` in solution file was at wrong count - there was 56 projects in solution and reported number was 57.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue to this.  There was a project file which was referenced and had been renamed.  The .sln was not aware of the project file name change.  The fix was the checkout the .sln file, and update the reference to the project file.

Answer (score 0):

This method is allot easier and less time consuming:

1. Close the solution.
2. Go the the folder which contains the solution file.
3. Delete the hidden ".vs" folder.

It won't do any harm but if you're afraid you can always rename the folder instead of deleting it.

Comment: doesn't solve the issue OP is having...

Comment: Hi @ozkan, TFS settings are stored in the SUO file that is inside the hidden folder ".vs".
It worked for me and is easier then rebinding everything manually. So I'll leave this answer here.