# ASP.NET MVC 6 Project file cannot be loaded

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, tfs, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm having difficulties opening my MVC Core solution.

It all started after my computer crashed. Now, every time i try to open a solution, I get a popup "Projects have recently been added to this solution. Do you want tot get them from source control? Yes/No."

Project doesn't load, has "load failed" near it's name, and when I try to reload it, i get an error message: "The project * has been moved, renamed or is not on your computer."

I tried following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35357257/every-time-i-open-my-vs-solution-i-get-projects-have-recently-been-added-to-thi) advice to unbind the project from TFS, but I get the error: "The solution contains unloaded projects. Any changes you make will not affect the unloaded projects. It is strongly recommended that you reload all projects before continuing."

Any advice mates?

Comment: You can try to right-click the projects that have not been loaded and select a reload project option

Comment: Did you try to reload the projects that are unavailable?

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Run the Solution as Administrator. Run Visual Studio as administrator and then open the project form there.

Reason:
In ASP.net MVC projects, we generally need to setup the project to use IIS metafiles. In my project when I did a project reload form Visual studio, I got the following error.

[image]

Since it said "You do not have sufficient privileges to access IIS Websites", I ran VS as administrator which worked for me.

Answer (score -2):

1. Find out the projects that are unavailable under your solution, like the screenshot below:

   [image]
2. Then right click the projects, and click "Reload Project", check whether the error message persists:

   [image]

Comment: Failed reload.  Remove the project from the sln and add it manually: What's the next step after it claims the file doesn't exist, has been moved, or renamed?