# tfs 2010 with an upgrade visual studio 2012 want to download a Deploy.wdproj that was deteled with the last upgrade

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, tfs

I upgraded a visual studio 2012 web form application to Visual Studio 2012 and added the upgrade to tfs 2010. As part of this upgrade process, I removed a web deploy project from the solution file since I do not need the web  deploy 2010 project anything. The application is now being deployed as a publish website.

The problem is When I obtain  the updated solution file from TFS, it keeps saying 'projects have been recently added to this solution. Do you want to get them from source control? If I click yes, it wants to open -Deploy.wdproj that is not supported by the application.

If I click yes, nothing else happens. Should I get rid of this message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description and error message, this seems due to the project that was deleted from source control but still referenced in the `.sln`. The .sln was not aware of this. Please checkout the .sln file, and update the reference.

Another solution is unbinding and binding again the solution file.

> **1. Unbinding the solution file from TFS**
>
> Unbind the solution file (.sln) from TFS. Go to the menu File =>
>   Source Control => Change Source Control.
>
> [image: Unbinding the solution file]
>
> **2. Cleaning the solution file by deleting globalsection**
>
> Clean the solution file (.sln) by opening it in a text editor. Remove
>   all occurences of `GlobalSection(TeamFoundationVersionControl) =
>   preSolution`. Including the mentioned starting tag and the ending tag
>   `EndGlobalSection`.
>
> **3. Bind the solution file to TFS again**
>
> Finally bind the solution file (.sln) to TFS again. Do this in visual
>   studio by going to the menu`File => Source Control => Change Source
>   Control
>
> [image: Binding the solution file to TFS again]

Take a look at this similar question: [Every time I open my VS solution I get “Projects have recently been added to this solution. Do you want to get them from source control?”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35357257/every-time-i-open-my-vs-solution-i-get-projects-have-recently-been-added-to-thi) Hope this helps.

Comment: This answered by question. Thanks!